# Universal Image loader update

Tags: android, eclipse, universal-image-loader

i have easy question, how to update Universal Image Loader from 1.9.1 to 1.9.2. I tried to just add new jar into the libs folder. How to check if i have latest version?

Comment: if you use Android Studio + Gradle, it will make your life easier

Comment: But i use eclipse. Is it possible to convert my project to android studio?

Answer (score 0):

*You don´t have to use Android Studio, for Eclipse try this:*

**Build a new version using Maven, like this:**

`<dependency>
    <groupId>com.nostra13.universalimageloader</groupId>
    <artifactId>universal-image-loader</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.2</version>
</dependency>`

**Or simply download SNAPSHOT 1.9.3**

([1.9.3](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/blob/master/sample/libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.3-SNAPSHOT.jar))

**and check, whether you have this new API available:**

> DisplayImageOptions.targetSize(ImageSize)